# Is wrapping only possible for package bodies?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g, scripting

I am using oracle 11gR2 database in which I was trying to wrap my scripts. I read the documents and tried to wrap a sql script which contains a create table statement. I used below commands:

```
wrap iname=ORDER.sql oname=ORDER_TEST.sql
wrap iname=ORDER.sql oname=ORDER_TEST.wrp
wrap iname=ORDER.sql oname=ORDER_TEST.plb
```

But in all 3 format the files created have same codes visible, no encryption is happening. Also, I have tried same on a package body which get encrypted properly. 
Now, I need to know does only package bodies has this facility of wrapping. Can I wrap other scripts like create table, trigger, view etc..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PL/SQL Source Text Wrapping](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/wrap.htm#LNPLS016)

> You can wrap the PL/SQL source text for any of these stored PL/SQL
>   units, thereby preventing anyone from displaying that text with the
>   static data dictionary views *_SOURCE:
>
> - Package specification
> - Package body
> - Type specification
> - Type body
> - Function
> - Procedure

A script containing a `CREATE TABLE` statement does not fall into any of the above categories.

Also, keep in mind, unwrapping such source takes seconds (for example: http://www.codecrete.net/unwrapit/). Oracle generously classified this method as `low-assurance security` (see above URL), but I would rather classify this as `non-existent security`.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't even bother. It's security through obscurity

Comment: @Balazs Papp So, which will be the best method to secure the codes migrating to production instance? or simply saying, how to hide the codes/queries in oracle 11g db?

Comment: @SHS: why do you think you need to do that?

Comment: You can't. Wrapping also makes it hard for DBAs to do their job

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ Could you please explain how the wrapping makes DBAs job difficult? In which kind of scenarios ?